# I want to add the sum of a column in a mysql query output

Tags: mysql

I want to add the sum of a column in a mysql query output.

I have the query output inserted into a xlsx file.

that file should have the total of a particular column in the query output

Comment: Can you please add the schema, sample data and expected output to the question?

Answer (score 0):

suppose i want to find sum of a column parentareaid and show it in the result.
Then i can write: select sum(ar.parentareaid) from area ar